# Does Spring allow you to replace a property in a referenced bean?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have hierarchy in 7 beans like:

```
<bean id="bean01" class="myClass"...........
  <property ..... val-rev="bean1"/>

<bean id="bean1" ...........
  <property ..... val-rev="bean2"/>

 .......................

<bean id="bean6" ...........
  <property ..... val-rev="bean5"/>

 .......................
 <property name="reqProp" value="val1"/>
```

I need to create second bean very similar to first:

```
<bean id="bean02" class="myClass"...........
  <property ..... val-rev="bean1"/>

<bean id="bean1" ...........
  <property ..... val-rev="bean2"/>

 .......................

<bean id="bean6" ...........
  <property ..... val-rev="bean5"/>

 .......................
 <property name="reqProp" value="val2"/>
```

The problem that I wouldn't create second hierarchy of beans for bean02, but only create 2 different lowest level beans with different property.
Does it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use [bean inheritance](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions) by using the "parent" attribute.

Here the two beans would inherit from a single bean and only set the "reqProp" property.

[Here's another short tutorial.](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-configuration-inheritance/)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have inheritance. It is chain of references.

Comment: @user710818 Yes, you do have inheritance, because the chain of references are the same.